# What is pump.io?

Tags: social-networking

Recently I have been looking into the development of social networks and I often find references to pump.io. There is however very limited information available on what pump.io actually is. The official website says nothing more than: "It's a stream server that does most of what people really want from a social network." I found some more information on this website (http://slid.es/evanp/understanding-pumpio/fullscreen#/) but that still doesn't say a lot to me.

Could someone please provide an elaborate discussion on what pump.io actually is (and does)  to someone who does not know anything about (activity) stream servers? Maybe the better question is: "What is an activity stream server?"

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the term is one a lot of people are unfamiliar with and it makes a couple of distinctions that aren't immediately obvious even if you use and post to a pump.io site.

pump.io, as it is distributed, is really two programs with different sets of functions. One is the *Activity Stream Server* and the other is the *Web Client*.

At the risk of being pedantic, let me define each of the words. I know you know what the words mean, but I hope the specific contexts/usage will help:

- **Server**: a program which distributes information (usually) across a
  network.
- **Stream**: a (usually) chronological series of some sorts of pieces of information.
- **Activity**: a description or depiction of something someone is doing.

The Activity Stream Server is **a program which distributes** (server) a **chronological series** (stream) of **posts about stuff people do** (activities).

The distinction is important because the website part of a pump.io website is a client for the pump server—essentially no different from a desktop or smartphone pump.io client. It listens to the pump's stream of posts and sends new posts to the pump using the same API and data formats that standalone applications—or other pumps—do.

You could actually totally decouple the Web Client and have a fully-functioning pump.io instance without any website. Users on other pump sites could see your posts and you could see theirs, and you could comment back and forth. It would make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

ActivityStream is a JSON-based data format to describe "activities". The specification of ActivityStream 2.0 can be found at https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-core/ and the vocabulary of activities at https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-vocabulary/. To get the feeling of how the data format looks like you can have a look at the few examples at https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-core/#examples. More examples can be found throughout the two specifications.

Answer (score 1):

> pump.io is an activity stream server that does most of what people
>   really want a social network server to do.
>
> That's a pretty packed sentence, I understand, but I can try to unwind
>   it a little.
>
> "Activities" are the things we do in our on-line or off-line
>   life—waking up in the morning, going for a run, tasting a beer,
>   uploading a photo, adding a friend, eating a burrito, joining a group,
>   liking a blog post.
>
> pump.io uses a simple JSON format to represent all these kinds of
>   activities and many more. It organizes activities into streams—time
>   ordered lists of activities, with the newest first. Most streams are
>   organized by theme, like: all the things that my friends did, or all
>   the things that I did, or all the things anyone has done to this
>   picture.
>
> Programmers use a simple API to connect to a pump.io server and add
>   new activities. pump.io automatically organizes the activities into
>   streams and makes sure the activities get to the people who are
>   interested in them.
>
> And, really, that's what we want from a social network

Behrenshausen, B. (2013). 'Interview with Evan Prodromou, lead developer of pump.io'. Retrieved from: https://opensource.com/life/13/7/pump-io

Answer (score -1):

If you peer a few centimeters down the page on the official website, you'll see:

> What's it for? I post something and my followers see it. That's the
>   rough idea behind the pump.
>
> There's an API defined in the API.md file. It uses activitystrea.ms
>   JSON as the main data and command format.
>
> You can post almost anything that can be represented with activity
>   streams -- short or long text, bookmarks, images, video, audio,
>   events, geo checkins. You can follow friends, create lists of people,
>   and so on.
>
> The software is useful for at least these scenarios:
>
> - Mobile-first social networking
> - Activity stream functionality for an existing app
> - Experimenting with social software

Those last 3 items hopefully answer your question.

Currently, you can:

- install the nodejs-based pump.io server
- (or) sign up for an account on a public service
- post notes and pictures with configurable permissions
- log in to [web and client applications](https://github.com/e14n/pump.io/wiki/Clients) using your webfinger ID

Comment: I already referred to the official website in my question so I am aware of that.

As I also described in my question, it is unclear to me what an activity stream server is.